# Performance Issue : Adding ChildPanels in a Panel vertically taking a significant time

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am working on VSTO winforms for Outlook widget, my requirement is to add button in a child Panel and adding multiple child panel to a container Panel at runtime. 
 The number of childPanel depends on the number of loop iteration. Right now rendering the child panels in the container Panel is taking a long time and slowing down the application. 
 Pagination is part which I must implement but if the Iterations are less < 10 then also I am getting a late rendering. Please suggest me if there is a better way to do it or if you have a better alternate combination of controls which could give me the same look and feel. Thanks in advance.

```
                   foreach (var item in Items)
                    {
                        Button itemButton = new Button();
                        itemButton.Text = item.name;
                        itemButton.fieldType = item.type;
                        itemButton.fieldId = item.id;
                        itemButton.Click += itemHandler;

                        // add the button in the child panel
                        CustomItemPanel childItemPanel = new CustomItemPanel();
                        childItemPanel.Controls.Add(itemButton);

                        // add to the clicked container panel
                        containerPanel.Controls.Add(childItemPanel);

                    }
```

The reason why I want to add a panel in a panel is to add a RichTextBox control in the child panel on click of the button.

Below is the listing of child Panels containing Button in a container Panel :

[image]

When I click the button, I am adding a richTextBox in the childPanel of the clicked button as below :

[image]

Comment: looks like too much layout issue. try `containerPanel.SuspendLayout()` before the loop and `containerPanel.ResumeLayout()` after the loop. Refrence: [Control.SuspendLayout Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @bansi, this has substantially improved the rendering time, is there any scope of improvement other than the provided solution ?